# Proof for Irreducible Error statement in ISLR page 19

Tags: self-study, variance, prediction, expected-value, statistical-learning

This section of Introduction to Statistical Learning in R (page 19 in v6, statement 2.3) is motivating the difference between reducible and irreducible error (that is noted by $\epsilon$ and has mean zero).

> Consider a given estimate $\hat{f}$ and a set of predictors $X$, which yields the prediction $\hat{Y} = \hat{f}(X)$. Assume for a moment that both $\hat{f}$ and $\hat{X}$ are fixed. Then, it is easy to show that
>
> $E(Y - \hat{Y})^2 = E[f(X) + \epsilon - \hat{f}(X)]^2$
>
> $= [f(X) - \hat{f}(X)]^2 + Var(\epsilon)$

I'm having trouble getting the intermediate steps here. I understand that the expectation of the error in prediction should involve the variance of $\epsilon$ but I'd like to understand the proof.

I expanded to

$E(Y - \hat{Y})^2 = E[f(X) - \hat{f}(X)]^2 + 2E(\epsilon)E[f(X) - \hat{f}(X)] + E(\epsilon)^2$

and I see that I have $E(\epsilon)$ and $E(\epsilon)^2$ terms that could lead to $Var(\epsilon)$, but I'm stuck trying to fit some of the basic expected value and variance manipulations to it.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Because you tell us the mean of $\epsilon$ is $0$, you may substitute $0$ for $E(\epsilon)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(\epsilon)$ for $E(\epsilon^2)$ in your formula.  What does that produce?

Comment: OK, with that I solved it. Is it preferred for me to answer my own question with this information, or just edit my question with the answer?

Comment: The preference is to post an answer, please.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[(Y-\hat Y)^2\right]
  &=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(f(X)+\epsilon-\hat{f}(X)\right)^2\right] \\
  &=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(f(X)+\epsilon-\hat{f}(X)\right)
                    \left(f(X)+\epsilon-\hat{f}(X)\right)\right] \\
  &=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)
                    \left(f(X)+\epsilon-\hat{f}(X)\right)
                   +\epsilon
                    \left(f(X)+\epsilon-\hat{f}(X)\right)\right] \\
  &=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)^2
                    +\epsilon
                     \left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)
                   +\epsilon
                    \left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)
                   +\epsilon^2\right] \\
\text{Because the expectation is linear}&\\
  &=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)^2\right]
   +\mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon^2\right]
   +2\mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon
                     \left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)\right] \\
\text{Because the expectation of $f$ and $\hat{f}$ are constant}&\\
  &=\left[f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right]^2
   +\mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon^2\right]
   +2\mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon
                     \left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)\right] \\
\text{Because the mean of $\epsilon$ is zero}&\\
  &=\left[f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right]^2
   +\mathbb{E}\left[\epsilon^2\right] \\
\text{Because the variance of $\epsilon$ is $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon^2)$}&\\
  &=\left[f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right]^2 + \text{Var}(\epsilon)
\end{align*}

Comment: With self-study questions, we generally prefer giving hints rather a full answer. However, since the question is rather old, and the question hasn't been asked as part of a homework sheet that other students might copy later (but rather, a difficulty following a textbook), I think the provision of a full answer in this case is actually helpful.

Comment: Ah, I see. The answer was actually self-study myself. I came looking for the  answer to the same question, having prepared everything but the last two steps. I guess I wanted to get credit for my work :D

Comment: You can read [our policy on self-study questions here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), but I thought this was fine :)

Comment: I appreciate the posted answer because I realized I hadn't properly solved it when I was going to post the solution to my own question.

Comment: why are $f$ and $\hat{f}$ constant?

Comment: Second @baxx question. Why are $f$ and $\hat{f}$ constant?

Comment: Because this is relative to a single fit.

Comment: Why f  and f^  are constant?:  Suppose you have a 1 X 3 matrix. You have X (input variable), Y (real measured value of outcome) and a Y hat (you used a linear function f  hat, or in layman terms a formula to get Y hat). Now Y = f(X) + error. Here, whenever you try to measure Y, it will always differ from the previous measurement, but the underlying f(X) remains the same. It would always be the ever-changing error term making the difference. And when you calculate Y hat as an estimation for Y, you would use the same f hat on the same  X, resulting in the same Y hat. So you see the nuance here.